# Why is the route on my google map not showing up

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to get the route between 2 directions displayed on my google map, by following documentation and examples i got this so far:

```
<?php
function get_coordinates($city, $street)
{
    $address = urlencode($city.','.$street);
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=Netherlands";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response);
    $status = $response_a->status;

    if ( $status == 'ZERO_RESULTS' )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $return = array('lat' => $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, 'long' => $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
        return $return;
    }
}
function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2) //rekent afstand en tijd uit
{
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=nl-NL";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
    $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];

    return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
}
$coordinates1 = get_coordinates('Hardenberg','Parkweg');
$coordinates2 = get_coordinates('Zwolle','Stationstraat');
if ( !$coordinates1 || !$coordinates2 )
{
    echo 'Bad address.';
}
else
{
    $dist = GetDrivingDistance($coordinates1['lat'], $coordinates2['lat'], $coordinates1['long'], $coordinates2['long']);
    echo 'Afstand: <b>'.$dist['distance'].'</b><br>Reis tijd met auto: <b>'.$dist['time'].'</b>';
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $coordinates1['lat']; ?>", "<?php echo $coordinates1['long']; ?>"),
          zoom: 10
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        document.getElementById('<?php echo $coordinates1; ?>');
        document.getElementById('<?php echo $coordinates2; ?>');
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin: document.getElementById('<?php echo $coordinates1; ?>').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('<?php echo $coordinates2; ?>').value,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCE86-tBBJ647owGUS5OhGeJ9CHDficids&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I thought it should work like this but its not not showing the route on the map someone any idea what I did wrong in this code? 
It is giving the correct output about the distance and traveltime the only thing missing is the line that shows the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your code. Please check below.

In your code you did not call the function which direction is mapped on map :

```
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,directionsDisplay);
```

Also you have written wrong latitude and longitude in JS.

```
origin: document.getElementById('<?php echo $coordinates1; ?>').value,
destination: document.getElementById('<?php echo $coordinates2; ?>').value
```

Try this :

```
<?php
function get_coordinates($city, $street)
{
    $address = urlencode($city.','.$street);
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=Netherlands";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response);
    $status = $response_a->status;

    if ( $status == 'ZERO_RESULTS' )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $return = array('lat' => $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, 'long' => $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
        return $return;
    }
}
function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2) //rekent afstand en tijd uit
{
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=nl-NL";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
    $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];

    return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
}
$coordinates1 = get_coordinates('Hardenberg','Parkweg');
$coordinates2 = get_coordinates('Zwolle','Stationstraat');
if ( !$coordinates1 || !$coordinates2 )
{
    echo 'Bad address.';
}
else
{
    $dist = GetDrivingDistance($coordinates1['lat'], $coordinates2['lat'], $coordinates1['long'], $coordinates2['long']);
    echo 'Afstand: <b>'.$dist['distance'].'</b><br>Reis tijd met auto: <b>'.$dist['time'].'</b>';
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $coordinates1['lat']; ?>", "<?php echo $coordinates1['long']; ?>"),
          zoom: 10
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService,directionsDisplay);
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin: new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $coordinates1['lat']; ?>", "<?php echo $coordinates1['long']; ?>"),
          destination: new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $coordinates2['lat']; ?>", "<?php echo $coordinates2['long']; ?>"),
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
            alert(status);  
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCE86-tBBJ647owGUS5OhGeJ9CHDficids&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```